# Offset Not Working Reliably Due to Skipped Pages in `includepdf` / Automatic `openright`-Detection

Tags: pdfpages

## Offset Not Working Reliably Due to Skipped Pages in `includepdf` / Automatic `openright`-Detection

### Situation and Problem

For my purposes I want to merge and offset a set of given pdfs.
When I include a single pdf and set the `offset`-option everything works fine, but including several leads to fails of `offset` for certain parts.

More precisely it will fail, if pages were skipped, as the previous chapter ended at an odd page number; e.g. `chapter_1.pdf` ends at page 49 but `chapter_2.pdf` opens right at 51.
That means parts 1 and 3 in the MWE work for me but 2 and 4 do not.

I worked around this by manually checking for "missing" pages, as adding `openright` to all calls did not work. However, I would prefer an option.

Since I am not the author I can not upload the original files, but the only relevant information is the `twoside` typesetting and the fact that chapters start at odd pages.

### Question

> How to set a twoside offset in pdfpages with skipped pages?

or

> How to detect skipped pages and automatically add `openright`?

### MWE

Generate a few 'importee'-copies and then adjust names if necessary in 'importer'.

`importee.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-14]

\end{document}
```

`importer.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    twoside % to make offset odd/even-page-sensitive
]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdfset{pages=-, offset={25pt 0pt}} % not reliably working for all calls

\begin{document}

\includepdf[]{./test_importee_1.pdf}
\includepdf[]{./test_importee_2.pdf}
\includepdf[]{./test_importee_3.pdf}
\includepdf[]{./test_importee_4.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the offset works fine, the problem is that your includes start sometimes on an even and sometimes on an odd page, you want a different offset in every case.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, indeed! That is what I am trying to explain in the "More precisely ..." part. I want the `openright` option every time a previous chapter ended on an odd page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your example might look weird at first glance, it is not a bug and totally correct. Please reread the description of `offset` in the documentation. It says:

> **offset** Displaces the origin of the inserted pages. The argument should be two
> dimensions, separated by space. In ‘oneside’ documents positive values
> shift the pages to the right and to the top margin, respectively, whereas
> in ‘twoside’ documents positive values shift the pages to the outer and
> to the top margin, respectively.

Thus in `twoside` documents `offset` shifts the recto and verso pages in opposite directions. This option was introduced to accommodate the layout when including a oneside-document into a twoside-document.

Things are getting more complicated when trying to include a twoside-document into a oneside-document, or a twoside-document into a twoside-document. Now you need a positive shift if starting on a recto page, and a negative shift if starting on a verso page. The problem being that you do not know beforehand wheather you are starting on a recto or verso page. And so far there's no support from pdfpages for this case, but it's not so difficult to achieve this, once you have a working `\ifthispageodd` macro. (Note that such a macro is not as easy to implement as it might seem.) E.g. koma-script provides a correct `\Ifthispageodd`. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[twoside, paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\includepdfset{pages=-}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\Ifthispageodd{%
  \includepdf[offset={25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}{%
  \includepdf[offset={-25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}

\newpage
\Ifthispageodd{%
  \includepdf[offset={25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}{%
  \includepdf[offset={-25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}

\newpage
\Ifthispageodd{%
  \includepdf[offset={25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}{%
  \includepdf[offset={-25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}

\newpage
\Ifthispageodd{%
  \includepdf[offset={25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}{%
  \includepdf[offset={-25pt 0pt}]{importee.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: `\Ifthispageodd` is defined in package `scrextend.sty`, which can be used without loading a koma-script class.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solves the problem. However it does so only for `scrartcl` and without keeping the chapter openings on right-pages. The second not really being an issue, as one can easily define this include-command: `\newcommand{\myinclude}[1]{\newpage%
\Ifthispageodd{%
  \includepdf[]{#1}}{%
  \includepdf[openright]{#1}}}`. 
Any hints on oddpage-detection for non-koma-script classes though?

Comment: `\Ifthispageodd` is defined in koma-script package scrextend.sty, which can be loaded without using a kom-script class.